# android onBackPressedDispatcher not run

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

i want provide custom back navigation

i have this code on `onCreate` in `Fragment`:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(
            this,
            object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
                override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                    Log.e("onCreate:", "back pressed invoked")
                }
            }
        )
        Log.e("onCreate: ", "Run")
    }
```

fragment declare :

```
class InsertFragment : Fragment() {

}
```

i using navigation component and my library version is:

```
def nav_version = "1.0.0"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
```

when i click on back button, i have no output `Log`, what i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onBackPressedDispatcher` is for handle device back button.

because of this `Log` only run when device back button press

Answer (score 0):

**Not****

If you use navigation component, should look at this

Do not do this :

```
activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback(
        object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                //todo
            }
        }
)
```

Do this instead :

```
 activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback(
        viewLifecycleOwner,
        object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                //todo
            }
        }
 )
```

Why we use `viewLifecycleOwner` in that `callback` because backpress function will be cleared after navigate to next fragment. If you don't use it, the whole container activity backpresss function will be triggered and affects to other fragments in that container activity.